# Efficient mechanism to extract data from a SQL Server Table

Tags: c++, odbc

I have a SQL Server table with a large number of rows, I need to load all of this data into memory on startup

Currently I have been doing the following where I have been allocating an SQLHENV, SQLHDBC and finally a SQLHSTMT and then calling SQLExecDirect followed by SQLFetch in a loop as shown below, with multiple calls to SQLGetData in each iteration for each of the columns.

```
  if (SQL_SUCCESS == (rc = SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLCHAR *)inodeQuery.get(), SQL_NTS)))
    {
        SQLGUID id;
        SQLLEN  idLength;

        /*.... initialize other params.... */

        while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {

            SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_C_GUID, &id, 0, &idLength);


            /*... additional calls to SQLGetData for each column ....*/

        }

        SQLFreeStmt(sqlStmtHandle, SQL_CLOSE); // get all the results from the query before freeing the handle.
    }
```

I wonder if there is a more efficient mechanism to bulk load all of the data or at least multiple rows in one iteration, would appreciate you folks's input on whether the following is possible.

1. I would basically like to reduce the number of times I call SQLFetch
2. I would also like to avoid having to call SQLGetData for each column

Comment: No chance of writing a smarter query?

Comment: The issue I want to address here is how to load all of the data in the most efficient way, or in other words there are no predicates here in the SQL query, the intention being to load everything into memory during initialization in order to avoid having to hit the disk during regular operation.